# assembly - relative jump out of range

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I've made an assembly code as shown below. 
The problem is that when I run the program, an error message appears: "relative jump out of range". The problem is that the content of the **loop** is too long. Can someone help me and tell me how to change the **loop** in order it will work?

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
INCLUDE 'gvahim.mac'

DATASEG
; --------------------------
pos_dig_7 db 0
pos_div_7 db 0
print db 0
index db 0
ARR_DIV_7 db 100 dup(?)
ARR_DIGIT_7 db 100 dup(?)
; --------------------------
CODESEG
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
    mov cx, 100
    loop_1:
        mov [print], 0
        inc [index]
        mov ax, 0
        mov al, [index]
        mov bl, 7
        div bl
        cmp ah, 0
        jne jump1
        mov [print], 1
        mov bx, 0
        mov bl, [pos_div_7]
        mov bl, [index]
        mov [ARR_DIV_7+bx], al
        inc [pos_div_7]
            jump1:
                mov ax, 0
                mov al, [index]
                mov bl, 10
                div bl
                cmp al, 7
                jne jump2
                mov [print], 2
                jump2: 
                    cmp ah, 7
                    jne jump3
                    mov [print], 2  
                        jump3:
        mov [print], dl
        cmp dl, 0
        jne next1
        mov ax, 0
        mov al, [index]
        jmp end_of_pro
        next1: 
            cmp dl, 1
            jne next2
            mov ax, 77
            next2:
                cmp dl, 2
                jne end_of_pro
                mov bx, 0
                mov bl, [pos_dig_7]
                mov al, [index]
                mov [ARR_DIGIT_7+bx], al
                inc [pos_dig_7]
                mov ax, 777
        end_of_pro:
        call PRINT_NUM_DEC
        call NEW_LINE
    loop loop_1
; --------------------------
exit:

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
INCLUDE 'gvahim.asm'

END start
```

Answer (score 4):

Begin by moving unnecessary operations.  For instance, it's unclear what you're actually trying to accomplish here, but at a glance it appears that you `mov [print], <value>` repetitively in a number of cases.  Despite all of the initial gyrations, it appears that `mov [print],dl` will always happen.  If that's the case, remove all of the rest of them, which eliminates at least four multi-byte operations from your code.

You could also get around this issue by avoiding the `loop` statement.  Instead, check the value of the counter yourself and use a `jmp`:

```
dec  cx
cmp  cx, 0        ; Not actually needed - preceding line will set ZF at zero
jz   finished
jmp  loop1
finished:
<code continues>
```

This allows a near jump rather than a short jump, which is what `loop` is effectively using.  A short jump, which `loop` implements, must be within -128 and +127 bytes of the loop instruction

Comment: Thank you vey much for helping

Comment: In the same category "unnecessary operations", you could strip the `cmp cx,0` instruction from the example. The `dec cx` already sets the required flags!

Comment: And unless this is real 8086 code,then writing the opposite conditional jump `jnz loop1` would be clearer. (1 jump less)

Comment: @Fifoernik it might be clearer, but if the short jump is too far for a branch on the preceding line . . .

Comment: @WeatherVane Exactly... hence my preference to use a jmp to allow a near jump to be encoded.

Comment: @Fifoernik you are correct about the `dec cx`.  I elected to leave the `cmp` in since this seems as though a beginner question, but I've added a comment to clarify.